# Generics or just use overloads?

Tags: c#, oop, class, generics, overloading

I have 3 classes, all share similar properties. 3 of the properties are named exactly the same across all 3 classes. Rather that write 3 methods (one for each class) is there some way I can utilise generics here?

```
public static String GetAString(ActivityMedia activityMedia)
{
   return activityMedia.name;
}

public static String GetAString(AuditMedia auditMedia)
{
   return auditMedia.name;
}

public static String GetAString(VehicleMedia vehicleMedia)
{
   return vehicleMedia.name;
}
```

EDIT: Obviously with the aim of simply passing an object of one of those 3 class types to GetAString()

Comment: Are these classes sharing one interface?

Comment: Is it an option to give these classes a common `Media` superclass or interface?

Comment: They don't share one interface no. They are just completely separate classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. introduce interface with a single `string Name` property
2. mark all three classes by interface
3. Now you can assess media Name directly I've no idea why you need a method for this but anyway, you can create extension method for the interface type `IMedia`

```cs
interface IMedia
{
    string Name { get; }
}

class ActivityMedia : IMedia
class AuditMedia : IMedia
class VehicleMedia : IMedia

static class MediaExtensions
{
   public static string GetName(this IMedia instance)
   {
          return instance.Name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think its redundant to implement Name property on all ActivityMedia, AuditMedia, VehicleMedia classes if you use interface? Although interface has different purpose

Comment: You do not need implement it because all three media already has Name property, thi is let's say marker interface

Comment: Its duplicate, isn't it? What you say?

Answer (score 3):

If they are completely unrelated, one option is to use `dynamic` (if you're on C# 4):

```
public static String GetAString(dynamic d){
    return d.name;
}
```

Edit:

If you're not using C# 4.0, you can use reflection:

```
public static string GetAString(object o)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo name = o.GetType().GetProperty("name");
    return (string) name.GetValue(o, null);
}
```

Comment: We're not on 4 yet unfortunately. That looks like the perfect solution if we were though. I'm going to look into that.

Comment: Where is .NET 4 was mentioned?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use reflection.

Comment: I don't understand where this discussion is going!? Vlad has suggested a solution for if I were coding in C# 4, that's all.

Comment: @ChrisBD : obviously you come here a bti later so was not able to see original answer without specifying `if .NET 4...`

Comment: I guess, this question more on design issue rather than implementation

Comment: It's a design issue only if the OP has access to the source code of their 3 classes and there are no restrictions on changing them.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use an interface...

```
public interface INameable
{
   String Name { get; }
}

public static String GetAString(INameable nameable)
{
   return nameable.Name;
}
```

Although at this point you probably don't even need the GetAString method?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with an interface

```
public interface INamedMedia
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

then your method becomes

```
public static String GetAString(INamedMedia media)
{
    return media.Name;
}
```

and your classes implement `INamedMedia`

```
public class Media : INamedMedia
{
    public string Name { get { return "Media"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought that an interface would be the ideal solutions here:

```
public interface IMedia
{
    public String Name { get; }
}
```

and then you could have your static method taking that interface type as it's parameter:

```
    public static String GetAString(IMedia media)
    {
        return media.Name;
    }
```

Or all of your media classes could derive from a base type which contains the property you require and pass that into the method instead of the interface.

It's difficult to tell you which is the better option because it depends on the complexity of your application and the inheritance chain already.

This [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dipenlama22/Inheritance_Versus_Interfaces07142006043113AM/Inheritance_Versus_Interfaces.aspx) may be of help

Answer (score 2):

you do not need generics, you need OOP and inheritance.

Make `ActivityMedia`, `AuditMedia` and `VehicleMedia` all to either implement a base interface like `IMedia` or derive a basic class like `MediaBase`

then you write the method `GetAString` only once which accepts either an `IMedia` object or a `MediaBase` object.

another option could be that you override the default `ToString` method in `ActivityMedia`, `AuditMedia` and `VehicleMedia` so to just return the name property then you will just call `ToString` without the need of any `GetAString` method.

Answer (score 2):

Generics won't help you here if these classes share no common ancestry. The solution is to arrange that they do share common ancestry by declaring an interface with a `name` property. Make each class implement that interface and then you can have a single `GetAString` function.

Answer (score 2):

If the three classes have a sub set of the same properties your better off implementing a base class instead with the common properties and methods declared in the base class which the three media classes are derived from.

```
public class ActivityMedia : Media 
{

}

public class Media
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

This way the three classes have one set of methods defined in one place making the code much easier to maintain. while giving you the flexibility to put class specific methods in their derived implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It's more logical to implement inheritance here rather than generics.

You can also use `Interface` but that would make your `Name` property duplicate on all your  `ActivityMedia`, `AuditMedia`, `VehicleMedia` classes.

Consider a base class `Media`

```
public class Media
{
    // consider all properties that are common
    // on Media domain
    public string Name { get; set }
}
```

And inherit `ActivityMedia`, `AuditMedia`, `VehicleMedia` from `Media` class.

```
public class ActivityMedia : Media
{
    // other properties on ActivityMedia domain
}

public class AuditMedia : Media
{
    // other properties on AuditMedia domain
}

public class VehicleMedia : Media
{
    // other properties on VehicleMedia domain
}
```

And now use `Media` class on your `GetAString` method

```
public static String GetAString(Media activityMedia)
{
   return activityMedia.name;
}

public static String GetAString(Media auditMedia)
{
   return auditMedia.name;
}

public static String GetAString(Media vehicleMedia)
{
   return vehicleMedia.name;
}
```

Comment: Inheritance sometimes a devil, and when you want to share single property across three classes it would be a bad idea to do it via base class (moreover not abstract)

Answer (score 1):

This is where inheritance comes to your rescue. Have such base class:

```
public class Media
{
    public string name { get { return "Media"; } }
}
```

Then each class will inherit and define its own name:

```
public class ActivityMedia : Media
{
    public new string name { get { return "Activity Media"; } }
}
```

And finally:

```
public static String GetAString(Media media)
{
    return media.name;
}
```

Edit: as you're stuck with your current design, you can use reflection:

```
public static String GetAString(object media)
{
    PropertyInfo propName = media.GetType().GetProperty("name");
    if (propName != null)
        return propName.GetValue(media, null);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: It would not be my decision to re-design these classes to inherit from a media class though. I'm pretty much stuck with working with the separate classes for now. I see what you mean though and I take it on board as an otherwise spot on answer.

Comment: See my edit, it will just look for property called "name" and get its value no matter what the object type is.